# Click a button on dynamically changed element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

When you link to some site on the Facebook chat, I always click the small x so the preview disappears. I hate doing this, as I send probably hundreds of links every day, and the previews are just rubbish 9/10 times.

I am creating an userscript to fix this, but since it's loading dynamically, I cannot simply click the button when it appears. This is what it looks like when I want to click the button:

```
$(".fbNubFlyoutAttachments").find("button:contains('Remove')").click();
```

Basically it finds the class fbNubFlyoutAttachments and then finds the button containing "Remove". Then it clicks the element and the preview disappears. Pretty easy.

However, when I get to the point of checking when a link has been posted.. we're getting into some tricky stuff here. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(document).bind("DOMSubtreeModified ", ".fbNubFlyoutAttachments", function(){
    $(".fbNubFlyoutAttachments").find("button:contains('Remove')").click();
});
```

However. `$(document).bind("DOMSubtreeModified"` triggers a lot, since the DOM changes a lot, which causes the stack to be filled pretty much instantly, and then the page freezes up. It would be nice to just do `$(".fbNubFlyoutAttachments").bind("DOMSubtreeModified"` but that is not possible (to my knowledge).

This is what I currently do, which works, but could take up to a second to trigger and it's using computing resources without the need for it:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(".fbNubFlyoutAttachments").find("button:contains('Remove')").click();
}, 1000);
```

How can I do this in a good way through my userscript? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of use `DomSubtreeModified` event [which is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

`DOM mutation events` has a problems with performance and stability so this is probably the reason why all freezes when you bind `DomSubtreeModified` event to document, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

So you can try to use `MutationObserver` in tampermonkey as follows:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.facebook.com/*
// @grant        none
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';


$(function() {
    // element to observer
    var body = document.querySelector('body');

    // create the trigger function
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
        $(".fbNubFlyoutAttachments").find("button:contains('Remove')").click();
    });

    // configure the element to observe and the changes you want to check
    observer.observe(body, { subtree: true, childList : true, characterData : true});


});
```

Check also the [attributes of the observer method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit)

Additionally you can filter the actions depending on the mutations array of object received in [`MutationObserver` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord).

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting a `failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` error when I run my script. Could it be because the elements are dynamically changed when something happens? Since it's Facebooks and I could basically have 10 chats open, I need to select all the windows open at any given time (which is why I have an `setInterval(function()..)` right now).

Comment: @snorlax sorry I don't explain myself pretty well and I also didn't try the first solution I was provide... I make a review so I hope now it's more accurate `:)`.

Comment: Wow, it really seems to work great! However, it's doing A LOT of unnecessary computing. Every time you enter a character into the chat, it will trigger the click, even though no link has been sent. Also when you load the page, it will trigger it like 15-20 times. Isn't that unnecessary? It works great though!

Comment: @Snorlax yes too much. You can remove `characterData : true` option to avoid that the event fires for every character you enter in a chat. Additionally you can play with another options or return mutation trying to reduce the unnecessary computing,  sorry I'm not an expert on `MutationObserver` `:)`.

Comment: Yeah I'm definitely going to play around with it a bit! Thanks a lot! This is much better than using intervals haha. Instead of doing a selector on the body-tag, I went ahead and went down to #pagelet_dock - With the body-selector, it would basically trigger every time something happens on the page.

Comment: @snorlax you're right `body` is too much, but I want to be a bit generic an not attach to a specific facebook element which could change or disappear in futur, but of course attach on a deeper element on the DOM can avoid a lot of unnecessary calls `:)`.

Comment: Yep you're completely right. I went ahead and changed it a bit down, so it won't get triggered 24/7 haha. Thanks once again!